# JsSip client with non secure websocket over https

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, websocket, jssip

I have been testing with jssip in firefox. I was able to load http://tryit.jssip.net. Although now this is redirected to secure channel over https://tryit.jssip.net. Which further does not allow ws:// connection.

Following is the jssip client error:

JsSIP:Transport connecting to WebSocket ws://a.b.c.d:p +2s
jssip.js:23543 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://tryit.jssip.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://a.b.c.d:p/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.W3CWebSocket @ jssip.js:23543Transport.connect @ jssip.js:19149(anonymous function) @ jssip.js:20215
jssip.js:22841 JsSIP:ERROR:Transport error connecting to WebSocket ws://a.b.c.d:p: SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS. +0ms
jssip.js:22666 JsSIP:UA transport ws://a.b.c.d:p failed | connection state set to 2 +1ms

Is there any way to use in non secure way or is it mandated? If so I searched hard but could not find anywhere on jssip release or version notes.

Answer (score 0):

On an https webpage, only passive (like image or css) mixed (insecure) content will work .

So you must use wss if it's hosted on an https webpage.